# Generate three rows in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table

```
SELECT TableCode, Col1, Col2
FROM TableA
WHERE TableCode = 23
```

Result of Table:

```
TableCode   |  Col1    |   Col1
23          | CustCode |    QS
23          | CatCode  |    QS
```

After that i wrote one query on TableA which return following output

Query :

```
SELECT TableCode,x.ColCode,
       x.ColumnName + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.COL ORDER BY X.COL)) [ColumnName],X.Values,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X.COL ORDER BY X.COL) [RowNo]
FROM TableA a CROSS APPLY   
     (SELECT 1 ColCode,'ParaName' ColumnName,Col1 Values
      UNION ALL  
      SELECT 2,'ParaSource',Col2   
     ) x
WHERE TableCode = 23;
```

Result :

```
TableCode | ColCode | ColumnName | Values |   RowNo
23       |   1     | ParaName_1 | CustCode |    1
23       |   1     | ParaName_2  | CatCode |    2
23       |     2   | ParaSource_1 | QS     | 1 
23        |   2    | ParaSource_2 | QS     | 2
```

And i required following output:

Required Output :

```
TableCode | ColCode | ColumnName | Values |   RowNo
23       |   1     | ParaName_1 | CustCode |    1
23       |   1     | ParaName_2  | CatCode |    2
23       |   1     | ParaName_3  | Null |   3
23       |     2   | ParaSource_1 | QS     | 1 
23        |   2    | ParaSource_2 | QS     | 2
23        |   2    | ParaSource_3 | null   | 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a couple of [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) along with the [table value constructor `(values (...),(...))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)
 to `cross join` numbers 1, 2, and 3 then using a `left join` to return 3 rows per `TableCode` even when you do not have three rows in the source table.

```
;with numbered as (
  select *, rn = row_number() over (order by (select 1))
  from TableA
  where TableCode = 23
)
, cte as (
  select distinct tc.TableCode, a.Col1, a.Col2, v.rn
  from numbered tc 
    cross join (values (1),(2),(3)) v (rn)
    left join numbered a
      on a.TableCode = tc.TableCode
     and a.rn = v.rn
)
select 
    a.TableCode
  , x.ColCode
  , [ColumnName] = x.ColumnName + '_' + convert(varchar(5),a.rn)
  , X.Value
  ,[RowNo] = a.rn
from cte a
  cross apply (values (1,'ParaName',Col1),(2,'ParaSource',Col2)) 
    as x(ColCode, ColumnName, Value)
order by ColCode, RowNo;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CJU8986

returns:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+----------+-------+
| TableCode | ColCode |  ColumnName  |  Value   | RowNo |
+-----------+---------+--------------+----------+-------+
|        23 |       1 | ParaName_1   | CustCode |     1 |
|        23 |       1 | ParaName_2   | CatCode  |     2 |
|        23 |       1 | ParaName_3   | NULL     |     3 |
|        23 |       2 | ParaSource_1 | QS       |     1 |
|        23 |       2 | ParaSource_2 | QS       |     2 |
|        23 |       2 | ParaSource_3 | NULL     |     3 |
+-----------+---------+--------------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to do what you want:

```
SELECT TableCode, x.ColCode, v.*
FROM TableA a CROSS APPLY   
     (VALUES (1, 'ParaName-1', Col1, 1),
             (2, 'ParaName-2', Col2, 2),
             (3, 'ParaName-3', NULL, 2)
     ) v(ColCode, ColumnName, [Values], RowNo)
WHERE TableCode = 23;
```

I see no reason to use `row_number()` when you can just read in the correct values.  Also, `VALUES` is a SQL keyword so it is a really bad column name.

Comment: this is not help me above query not getting me the required output what about "ParaSource-1,ParaSource-2,ParaSource-3"